# mysql_num_fields(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource with timestamp greater than

Tags: php, mysql

mysql is outputting this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=> '0000-00-01'' at line 1

here is my code

```
 foreach($tables as $table)
  {
    //SELECT Everything from the table in use
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `".$table."` WHERE `timestamp` => '".$offline_time."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo mysql_error();
    //Return Number of fields/colulms in the table.
    $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
```

Comment: Are you sure that day 1 on month 0, year 0, is the date you want to retrieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//change : WHERE `timestamp` =>  to
WHERE `timestamp` >=
```

Hope it works

Answer (score 4):

I assume you mean `>=` not `=>` for ["equal or greater too"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_greater-than-or-equal)